# decryption using sqlcipher in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, sqlcipher

Okey, so i am studying sqlcipher and preparing a document on it. so far study shows that how to encrypt database, i could not find how to decrypt database. Like that i have few more questions.
I found that you can not perform coredata operation on encrypted database.so

```
1) Can i run a sql query on encrypted database.
2) so if i have to perform a coredata operation, so i have to decrypt the database.
3) and last but not least, how to do decryption using sqlcipher.
```

Please answer if these questions make sense.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this open source project [link](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data)

Comment: @ShamsAhmed, thanks. Link is looking very useful. I'll explore the project. Thanks again.

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132477/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-sqlcipher-database-file-on-command-line/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can perform a SQL query on an encrypted database, however the pages within a SQLCipher enabled SQLite database need to be decrypted prior to retrieving the unencrypted data.  In order to access an SQLCipher encrypted database, you need issue either the [`PRAGMA key`](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#key) command, or programmatically call [`sqlite3_key`](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlite3_key).  Additional documentation can be found [here](http://sqlcipher.net/), along with the mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/sqlcipher).