# connect to encrypted sqllite with key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, laravel-5.4

I have sqlite database file with this feature:

1. I have `database.sqllite` file
2. This database encrypted with key (I have the key)
3. I work with `Laravel 5.4`

How can I decrypt and connect to this database file?

this is my code

```
\Config::set('database.connections.sqlite.database', $sqlitePath);
/**
* create a connection to SQLite Database
*/
$databasae = \DB::connection('sqlite');
```

and I got this error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 26 file is encrypted or is not a database
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: @gehbiszumeis excuse me ,this is my mistake. now update the question

Comment: where are you providing the key to connect to the database?

Comment: @Muhammad I encrypted with DB Browser for SQLlite , in this program get key for encrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, php or laravel had nothing to do with this,and I handel this problem with command line.
for more informaion read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132477/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-sqlcipher-database-file-on-command-line/25132478)